# Blurring non-rectangular region of an image, then downsample whole image - OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, mask, blur

I am using OpenCV3 to blur and downsample an image, I just want to blur the region inside the area defined by a binary mask like:

[image]

After that region is blurred, I would like to downsample the image without blurring the whole image again, so `pyrDown` is not useful for me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky way:

```
cv::Mat roi;
cv::blur(image & mask,roi,cv::Size(3,3));//Or whatever blurring you want
cv::Mat Result=(image & (~mask)) + roi;
cv::resize(result,result,cv::Size(New_Width,New_height)); // Or whatever downsampling you want
```

Comment: That is a good and tricky solution for grayscale images, however, the solution is not working if `image` is a 3-channel matrix, and `mask` a binary (single-channel) mask.

Comment: Works on 3-Channel. just add this : cv::cvtColor(mask,mask,cv::Gray2BGR); before the above code

Comment: I was cloning the binary mask into a 3-channel image as well, the problem was in the different precision of the values in the matrices... My fault, now it's working, thanks.